# Laravel Sail - How to get oci8 extension working for non-root (sail) user?

Tags: php, laravel, docker, oci8, laravel-sail

Is there someone knowledgeable about docker around?

I'm basically trying to install the oci8 extension inside a docker image (based on ubuntu) and failing at the last step. I've managed to compile the extension but for some reason it's only available to the root user.

[image: oci8 extension not working for sail user]

[image: oci8 extension working for root user]

My original steps were

```bash
...
RUN pecl channel-update pecl.php.net
RUN echo 'instantclient,/usr/local/instantclient_21_11' | pecl install oci8-2.2.0
RUN echo "extension=oci8.so" >> /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/30-oci8.ini
...
```

I've tried changing the last one to

```bash
RUN echo '; priority=30' >> /etc/php/7.4/mods-available/oci8.ini \
    && echo 'extension=oci8.so' >> /etc/php/7.4/mods-available/oci8.ini \
    && ln -s /etc/php/7.4/mods-available/oci8.ini /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/30-oci8.ini
```

And it still doesn't work. The error I get when I'm NOT a root user is

> PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library `'oci8.so'` (tried: `/usr/lib/php/20190902/oci8.so` (`libnnz21.so`: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), `/usr/lib/php/20190902/oci8.so.so` (`/usr/lib/php/20190902/oci8.so.so`: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory))

Doing `ldd /usr/lib/php/20190902/oci8.so` outputs the following

```
sail@:/var/www/html$ ldd /usr/lib/php/20190902/oci8.so
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff43cd0000)
    libclntsh.so.21.1 => /usr/local/instantclient/libclntsh.so.21.1 (0x00007f53320c4000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f5331ec4000)
    libnnz21.so => /usr/local/instantclient/libnnz21.so (0x00007f533184c000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f5331844000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f53316f4000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f53316cc000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f53316bc000)
    libaio.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libaio.so.1 (0x00007f53316b4000)
    libresolv.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007f5331694000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f53364ec000)
    libclntshcore.so.21.1 => /usr/local/instantclient/libclntshcore.so.21.1 (0x00007f53310e4000)
```

I thought there was a problem with `libnnz21.so` since it appears in the error but the file exists and is in the correct directory.
`libnnz21.so => /usr/local/instantclient/libnnz21.so`

[image: ls -lah /usr/local/instantclient/lib*]

This is my full dockerfile, edited from the one published with `php artisan sail:publish`

```bash
FROM ubuntu:20.04

LABEL maintainer="Taylor Otwell"

ARG WWWGROUP
ARG NODE_VERSION=16
ARG POSTGRES_VERSION=13

WORKDIR /var/www/html

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
ENV TZ=UTC

RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y gnupg gosu curl ca-certificates zip unzip git supervisor sqlite3 libcap2-bin libpng-dev python2 dnsutils \
    && curl -sS 'https://keyserver.ubuntu.com/pks/lookup?op=get&search=0x14aa40ec0831756756d7f66c4f4ea0aae5267a6c' | gpg --dearmor | tee /usr/share/keyrings/ppa_ondrej_php.gpg > /dev/null \
    && echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/ppa_ondrej_php.gpg] https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu focal main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ppa_ondrej_php.list \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y php7.4-cli php7.4-dev \
       php7.4-pgsql php7.4-sqlite3 php7.4-gd \
       php7.4-curl php7.4-memcached \
       php7.4-imap php7.4-mysql php7.4-mbstring \
       php7.4-xml php7.4-zip php7.4-bcmath php7.4-soap \
       php7.4-intl php7.4-readline php7.4-pcov \
       php7.4-msgpack php7.4-igbinary php7.4-ldap \
       php7.4-redis php7.4-xdebug \
    && php -r "readfile('https://getcomposer.org/installer');" | php -- --install-dir=/usr/bin/ --filename=composer \
    && curl -sLS https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_$NODE_VERSION.x | bash - \
    && apt-get install -y nodejs \
    && npm install -g npm \
    && curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | gpg --dearmor | tee /usr/share/keyrings/yarnkey.gpg >/dev/null \
    && echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/yarnkey.gpg] https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list \
    && curl -sS https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | gpg --dearmor | tee /usr/share/keyrings/pgdg.gpg >/dev/null \
    && echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/pgdg.gpg] http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt focal-pgdg main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y yarn \
    && apt-get install -y mysql-client \
    && apt-get install -y postgresql-client-$POSTGRES_VERSION \
    && apt-get -y autoremove \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

### Override: PHP oci8 extension
# Install Oracle Client
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y libaio1 libaio-dev unzip wget --no-install-recommends \
    && wget https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/linux/instantclient/2111000/instantclient-sdk-linux.x64-21.11.0.0.0dbru.zip \
    && wget https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/linux/instantclient/2111000/instantclient-sqlplus-linux.x64-21.11.0.0.0dbru.zip \
    && wget https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/linux/instantclient/2111000/instantclient-basic-linux.x64-21.11.0.0.0dbru.zip \
    && mkdir -p /opt/oracle \
    && cp instantclient-* /opt/oracle/ \
    && cd /opt/oracle/ \
    && unzip instantclient-basic-linux.x64-21.11.0.0.0dbru.zip -d /usr/local/ \
    && unzip instantclient-sdk-linux.x64-21.11.0.0.0dbru.zip -d /usr/local/ \
    && unzip instantclient-sqlplus-linux.x64-21.11.0.0.0dbru.zip -d /usr/local/ \
    && ln -s /usr/local/instantclient_21_11 /usr/local/instantclient \
    && ln -s /usr/local/instantclient/sqlplus /usr/bin/sqlplus  

# Install php7 oci8 extension
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/instantclient
ENV ORACLE_HOME=/usr/local/instantclient

RUN pecl channel-update pecl.php.net \
    && echo 'instantclient,/usr/local/instantclient_21_11' | pecl install oci8-2.2.0

RUN echo '; priority=30' >> /etc/php/7.4/mods-available/oci8.ini \
    && echo 'extension=oci8.so' >> /etc/php/7.4/mods-available/oci8.ini \
    && ln -s /etc/php/7.4/mods-available/oci8.ini /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/30-oci8.ini \
    && php -m

# Clean up
RUN apt-get -y remove wget unzip \
    && apt-get -y autoremove \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && rm -rf instantclient-basic-linux.x64-21.11.0.0.0dbru.zip \
    && rm -rf instantclient-sdk-linux.x64-21.11.0.0.0dbru.zip \
    && rm -rf instantclient-sqlplus-linux.x64-21.11.0.0.0dbru.zip
### End Override

RUN setcap "cap_net_bind_service=+ep" /usr/bin/php7.4

RUN groupadd --force -g $WWWGROUP sail
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash --no-user-group -g $WWWGROUP -u 1337 sail

COPY start-container /usr/local/bin/start-container
COPY supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf
COPY php.ini /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/99-sail.ini
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/start-container

EXPOSE 8000

ENTRYPOINT ["start-container"]
```

---

**EDIT: Here is the full working Dockerfile after the problem was solved. There might still be superfluous things in it but it's working.**

```bash
FROM ubuntu:20.04

LABEL maintainer="Taylor Otwell"

ARG WWWGROUP
ARG NODE_VERSION=16
ARG POSTGRES_VERSION=13

WORKDIR /var/www/html

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
ENV TZ=UTC

RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y gnupg gosu curl ca-certificates zip unzip git supervisor sqlite3 libcap2-bin libpng-dev python2 dnsutils \
    && curl -sS 'https://keyserver.ubuntu.com/pks/lookup?op=get&search=0x14aa40ec0831756756d7f66c4f4ea0aae5267a6c' | gpg --dearmor | tee /usr/share/keyrings/ppa_ondrej_php.gpg > /dev/null \
    && echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/ppa_ondrej_php.gpg] https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu focal main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ppa_ondrej_php.list \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y php7.4-cli php7.4-dev \
       php7.4-pgsql php7.4-sqlite3 php7.4-gd \
       php7.4-curl php7.4-memcached \
       php7.4-imap php7.4-mysql php7.4-mbstring \
       php7.4-xml php7.4-zip php7.4-bcmath php7.4-soap \
       php7.4-intl php7.4-readline php7.4-pcov \
       php7.4-msgpack php7.4-igbinary php7.4-ldap \
       php7.4-redis php7.4-xdebug \
    && php -r "readfile('https://getcomposer.org/installer');" | php -- --install-dir=/usr/bin/ --filename=composer \
    && curl -sLS https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_$NODE_VERSION.x | bash - \
    && apt-get install -y nodejs \
    && npm install -g npm \
    && curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | gpg --dearmor | tee /usr/share/keyrings/yarnkey.gpg >/dev/null \
    && echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/yarnkey.gpg] https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list \
    && curl -sS https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | gpg --dearmor | tee /usr/share/keyrings/pgdg.gpg >/dev/null \
    && echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/pgdg.gpg] http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt focal-pgdg main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y yarn \
    && apt-get install -y mysql-client \
    && apt-get install -y postgresql-client-$POSTGRES_VERSION \
    && apt-get -y autoremove \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

### Override: PHP oci8 extension
# Install Oracle Client
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y libaio1 libaio-dev unzip wget --no-install-recommends \
    && wget https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/linux/instantclient/2111000/instantclient-sdk-linux.x64-21.11.0.0.0dbru.zip \
    && wget https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/linux/instantclient/2111000/instantclient-sqlplus-linux.x64-21.11.0.0.0dbru.zip \
    && wget https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/linux/instantclient/2111000/instantclient-basic-linux.x64-21.11.0.0.0dbru.zip \
    && mkdir -p /opt/oracle \
    && cp instantclient-* /opt/oracle/ \
    && cd /opt/oracle/ \
    && unzip instantclient-basic-linux.x64-21.11.0.0.0dbru.zip -d /usr/local/ \
    && unzip instantclient-sdk-linux.x64-21.11.0.0.0dbru.zip -d /usr/local/ \
    && unzip instantclient-sqlplus-linux.x64-21.11.0.0.0dbru.zip -d /usr/local/ \
    && ln -s /usr/local/instantclient_21_11 /usr/local/instantclient \
    && ln -s /usr/local/instantclient/sqlplus /usr/bin/sqlplus \
    && echo /usr/local/instantclient_21_11 > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle-instantclient.conf \
    && ldconfig

# Install php7 oci8 extension
RUN pecl channel-update pecl.php.net \
    && echo 'instantclient,/usr/local/instantclient_21_11' | pecl install oci8-2.2.0

RUN echo '; priority=30' >> /etc/php/7.4/mods-available/oci8.ini \
    && echo 'extension=oci8.so' >> /etc/php/7.4/mods-available/oci8.ini \
    && ln -s /etc/php/7.4/mods-available/oci8.ini /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/30-oci8.ini \
    && php -m

# Clean up
RUN apt-get -y remove wget unzip \
    && apt-get -y autoremove \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && rm -rf instantclient-basic-linux.x64-21.11.0.0.0dbru.zip \
    && rm -rf instantclient-sdk-linux.x64-21.11.0.0.0dbru.zip \
    && rm -rf instantclient-sqlplus-linux.x64-21.11.0.0.0dbru.zip
### End Override

RUN setcap "cap_net_bind_service=+ep" /usr/bin/php7.4

RUN groupadd --force -g $WWWGROUP sail
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash --no-user-group -g $WWWGROUP -u 1337 sail

COPY start-container /usr/local/bin/start-container
COPY supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf
COPY php.ini /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/99-sail.ini
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/start-container

EXPOSE 8000

ENTRYPOINT ["start-container"]
```

Comment: I would use [this package](https://github.com/mlocati/docker-php-extension-installer) (I personally love it) or read [it's code](https://github.com/mlocati/docker-php-extension-installer/blob/master/install-php-extensions#L1077)

Comment: I might some other time. Thanks for the recommendation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the Instant Client [installation instructions](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/linux-x86-64-downloads.html) and run something like:

```
sudo sh -c "echo /usr/local/instantclient_21_11 > \
      /etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle-instantclient.conf"
sudo ldconfig
```

Also:

- Setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH is generally problematic with Apache because it needs to be set at the right place: and the shell generally isn't right.  Using `ldconfig` solves this.
- Never set ORACLE_HOME with Instant Client
- You don't need SQL*Plus for PHP (but I respect you might have it for some other reason)
- Some of the info in [Docker for Oracle Database Applications in Node.js and Python](https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/post/part-1-docker-for-oracle-database-applications-in-nodejs-and-python) will apply to PHP.

Comment: This solves it, thanks. I don't think those two lines were in the image I tried to reverse-engineer at first. Still, I'm just happy it works